# Automatic feature extraction from chess board positions

Tags: chess, feature-extraction, neural-network, deep-learning

I am working on a project where I take a chess board position (FEN string converted to binary) & it's evaluation score and feed it to a neural network. My aim is to make the neural network differentiate between good and bad positions.

**How I encode the position :** There are 12 unique pieces in chess i.e pawn, rook, knight, bishop, queen and king for *white* as well as *black*. I encode each piece using 4 bits with 0000 denoting an empty square. So the 64 squares are encoded into 256 bits and I use 6 more bits to denote game state like whose turn it is to move, king-castle status, etc.

**Problem :** Since the input space for chess positions is neither smooth nor uni-modal (one small change in the board position can result in a huge change in the evaluation score), the neural network doesn't learn well. Now, the next logical thing to somehow extract useful features (like material difference, center control, etc) and feed it to the network.

I do not want to hand pick the features as I want the network to learn everything by itself.  Therefore I am thinking of extracting features automatically using *autoencoders*. Is there any better way to accomplish this?

**Summary :** What is the best way to automatically extract features from a chess board position so that it can be fed into a neural network?

**UPDATE :** To generate training data, I have modified Stockfish to dump it's evaluation process into a log file. So every new move(position) it considers is written to a file as an FEN string along with it's eval score

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neural networks can give an approximation of any function. The only consideration to do is the dimensionality of the search space, which give constraints to the amount of data you have to get a good approximation.

For a supervised network (you use autoencoders, then I think you use some variant of backpropagation), it's difficult for me to immagine how you think to do the trainig using single positions because you need similar positions in your training set. Maybe your approach is different, but I'm convinced that second strategy (using features) is more promising. I think using positions require a huge amount of data training to get good results.

For features take a look [here](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Evaluation), and to the classical work of [Shannon](http://vision.unipv.it/IA1/ProgrammingaComputerforPlayingChess.pdf).

I taked also useful informations from the source code of [Crafty](http://www.craftychess.com/).

But you have to extract these informations from the FEN string.

Autoencoders are a way to give a reduction of data (good because increase performances). It seems to be better the use of Pincipal Component Analysys, as reported [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.2506.pdf).

I hope this can help you.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer @Francisco. I am not training the network using single positions.  I have modified Stockfish to dump it's evaluation process into a log file. So every new move(position) it considers is written to a file as an FEN string along with it's eval score. So I have a huge dump of similar positions(2 positions on adjacent lines in the log differ by 1 differently placed piece)